# Swixml 2.0 Anyway to update xml textfield text attribute from the application ?

Tags: java, swixml

Hi I have an xml generated text field from swixml 2.0
It is also setup to a specific text value.

```
<panel>
<textfield text="hello"> </textfield>
<panel>
```

This allows my textfield to appear in my panel with hello. What I would like to do is try to update this component by typing in my own text. I would hope there is away to save or update the xml component by having my application run a thread in which it runs through the component list and updates the text field.

So far I have found the container object and it does not appear to do what  I need it to do

can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

use the bindWith attribute

```
<panel>
<textfield bindWith="updateText"> </textfield>
<panel>
```

in the Java Frame/Dialog add a bean property

```
String getUpdateText() {
 return updateText;
}
void setUpdateText( String value ) {
    updateText = value;
    firePropertyChange("updateText",null,null);
}
```

when call setUpdateText() the text field will be automatically updated

Comment: It's the same behavior of INotifyPropertyChanged C# interface for update of a Xaml control.